# Changing tool tips to show x's value (datetime) and removing index from the tooltips

Tags: bokeh, python-3.7

I am learning to visualize data with bokeh and is stuck with HoverTool and it's tool tips. Here is the code that I have currently,

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter, HoverTool

register_matplotlib_converters()
pd.set_option('display.precision',4)
ticker_symbol = 'AAPL'

ts = TimeSeries(key=API_Key, output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=ticker_symbol,interval='1min', outputsize='full')

plt_tools = 'hover, pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset'
p = figure(title='Intraday Times Series', x_axis_label='Time', x_axis_type='datetime', y_axis_label='Price', plot_width=1280, plot_height=960, toolbar_location='below', tools=plt_tools)
h_line = HoverTool()
h_line.mode = 'vline'
h_line.tooltips = [('date','@index'),                          # not sure if this works
                   ('close','$@{4. close}{%0.2f}')]            # not sure if this works
h_line.formatters = {'date': 'datetime', '4. close': 'printf'} # not sure if this works
p.add_tools(h_line)
p.line(data.index.values, data['4. close'], legend_label=ticker_symbol, line_width=2)

output_file('lines.html')
show(p)
```

and the data looks like this

```
                      1. open   2. high    3. low  4. close  5. volume
date                                                                  
2019-12-23 09:35:00  281.0400  281.3582  281.0400  281.3582   171044.0
2019-12-23 09:34:00  281.0400  281.0400  281.0400  281.0400   129570.0
2019-12-23 09:33:00  281.3100  281.3900  281.2100  281.3300    97498.0
2019-12-23 09:32:00  281.4400  281.4800  281.1600  281.2800   194802.0
2019-12-23 09:31:00  281.4246  281.4246  281.4246  281.4246   957947.0
```

I manage to get the HoverTool and vline working but I'm getting 2 tooltips from the plot.
Stacked over each other ([stacked tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOSkk.jpg))
and the original tooltips without h_line.tooltips & h_line.formatters ([original tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxVFW.jpg))

How can I changed the tool tip to show like the block at the bottom instead of scientific number and price on the same line:

```
Date: DD-MM-YY HH:MM 
Close: xxx.xx
```

*example for Date - 01-01-20 13:15*
*example for Close - 291.86*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are passing data directly to `p.line`, rather than creating a `ColumnDataSource` and referencing the data from there. When you pass data directly to a glyph function, Bokeh has to create a `ColumnDataSource` for you, and since you have not told it what names to use for the columns, it can only use generic names like `'x'` and `'y'` (e.g. in this case). These generic names don't match up with the column names you configured for the hover tool. You can either:

- Change your hover tool configuration to use the generic column names `'x'` and `'y'`, or
- Create a `ColumnDataSource` and pass that as the `source` for `p.line`.

Note that if you want additional columns to also be usable for hover tools, then you must use the second option, with the all columns you want to be available to the tool.

See the User's Guide chapter [Providing Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html) for information on all of this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.  
Following up to 'Providing Data', I manage to play around with  

`data = {'x_values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'y_values': [6, 7, 2, 3, 6]}`

but putting `ColumnDataSource(data)` (the actual dataframe is reference as data that prints the table with the date index like the one from the question )return an error that says if i pass 'source=source' in p.line i will have to reference it or put in the data sequence. Is there a way to print the `ColumnDataSource(data)` dataframe so I can see what I need to refer into p.line?

Comment: If you make `source = ColumnDataSource(df)` to make a CDS from your DataFrame, the columns in the CDS are generally identical to whatever columns the DataFrame started with (plus perhaps an `index` column). Of course, you can also inspect the dict-like `source.data` directly, to see what keys it has. If you pass the `source` to `p.line` then you need to use the *column names* for things like x- and y-coordinates. e.g. `p.line('some_xcol', 'other_ycol', source=source)`